# To use or not Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was asked to model the following experiment:
Consider the n-th toss of a fair coin, and the event

$E$ = '$k$-th toss results in heads'.

I find easier to model the experiment using n random variables each Bernoulli distributed. But there is no mention of independence. The other formulation is using finite sequences of length n, but for some reason the probability measures seem to coincide. Does this imply that the defined random variables are necessarily indenpendent?

Comment: Coin tosses are traditionally treated as independent with no additional specification.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the $2^n$ possible sequences of heads and tails. If **by definition** these outcomes are equally likely then the model **coin**cides with the one based on distinct events and assuming independence.

Saying that the possible sequences are equally likely is equivalent to the assumption of independence.

Most importantly: both assumptions are arbitrary. You cannot justify either of them. Mathematics can tell only that the two hypotheses are quivalent.

BTW: [There is a similar question and some answers here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1236092/probability-of-cartesian-product-of-events/1236179#1236179).

Comment: thanks for the answer, and the link, I found it very useful

Answer (score 0):

When you assert that you can equivalently formulate a set of $n$ Bernoulli variates as a finite sequence of length $n$ *such that the probability of each possible sequence is equal*, you have imposed conditions that do imply the independence of the $n$ Bernoulli variates.

On the other hand, suppose for example you take a space of sequences such that the probability of any sequence is proportional to the longest run of identical results.  For $n=3$ this would be distributed as

$$\begin{array}{cl}
TTT:& \frac{3}{16} \\
TTH:& \frac{2}{16}\\
THT:& \frac{1}{16}\\
THH:& \frac{2}{16}\\
HTT:& \frac{2}{16}\\
HTH:& \frac{1}{16}\\
HHT:& \frac{2}{16}\\
HHH:& \frac{3}{16}
\end{array}
$$
Now you will find that the individual Bernoulli variates are not independent; in particular, the likelihood that $b_n = b_n-1$ is $\frac{5}{8}$ even though the likelihood that $b_n$ is heads without knowing any other $b_k$ is $\frac12$.

Comment: thanks, the example is very illustrative